# I cant figure out how to post angular's input form data in database (mongodb) using Django Rest API

Tags: django, angular, mongodb, rest, post

I cant figure out how to post angular's input form data in database (mongodb) using Django Rest API. There are not enough tutorials and documentations on the internet regarding the set of django and angular along with mongodb. or maybe im tunnel visioned now. If anyone has a link which might solve my problem it would be great.

Below is my angular's html file where you can see the form

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="InputAttackTitle">Attack Title</label>
              <input ngModel type="text" class="form-control" name="AttackTitle" id="InputAttackTitle" placeholder="Enter Attack Title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="InputAttackDescripton">Attack Description</label>
              <textarea ngModel class="form-control" name="AttackDescription" id="InputAttackDescripton" placeholder="Enter Attack Description" ></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <br>
          </div>
```

Here you can see component.ts file

```
export class IconsComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(config: NgbModalConfig, private modalService: NgbModal,private http:HttpClient, public fb:FormBuilder) 
  { 
    config.backdrop = 'static';
    config.keyboard = false;
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      AttackTitle: [''],
      AttackDescription: [null]
    })
  }
  AttackTitle:any;
  AttackDescription:any;
onSubmit(){

  var formData:any = new FormData();
  formData.append("AttackTitle",this.form.get('AttackTitle').value);
  formData.append("AttackDescription",this.form.get('AttackDescription').value);
  this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/attackinfo', formData).subscribe(
      (response) => {
      return console.log(response);
    },
      (error) => console.log(error)
    )
```

Below is the django's models class

```
class AttackInfo(models.Model):
AttackTitle=models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False)
AttackDescription = models.TextField(default='',blank=False)
```

And Below is the view file

```
@csrf_exempt
def AttackInfoAPI(request,id=0):
    if request.method=='GET':   
        attackinfo = AttackInfo.objects.all()
        attackinfo_serializer=AttackInfoSerializer(attackinfo,many=True)
        return JsonResponse(attackinfo_serializer.data,safe=False)
    elif request.method=='POST':
        attackinfo_data=JSONParser().parse(request)
        attackinfo_serializer=AttackInfoSerializer(data=attackinfo_data)
        if attackinfo_serializer.is_valid():
            attackinfo_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Added Successfully",safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Failed to Add",safe=False)
```

One more thing, The get request is working fine, Im only facing problems with Post request, probably because im just starting as a beginner (so im sorry XD)

Below is the URL code

```
urlpatterns=[
   re_path(r'^attackinfo$',views.AttackInfoAPI),
   re_path(r'^attackinfo/([0-9]+)$',views.AttackInfoAPI),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't add logging showing an error, the following is based on assumptions....

In Django you expect the body to be in JSON format, the FormData that is used in the http.post call should also be in JSON format.
Probably it can be achieved by changing the post call to:

```
this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/attackinfo', JSON.stringify(formData)).subscribe
```